# Как взять несколько выбранных option в select?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Мне нужно взять несколько значений из `option` для отправки на сервер а у меня получается взять только один.

С начало хотел написать вот так

```
let allSelect = [];
  select.onchange = e => {
    allSelect.push(select.value);
    console.log(allSelect);
}
```

Такой подход сохраняет все значение в массиве

Потом вот так

```
let allSelect = select.value;
```

Такой подход же сохраняет только одно значение.

Тоже не помогло

```js
const test = document.getElementById("test");
const select = document.getElementById("select ");
test.onsubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
 
  select.value;
}
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <select multiple id="select">
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test3</option>
  </select>
  
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583728/getting-the-selected-values-in-a-multiselect-tag-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `option.textContent` советую добавить какой-нибудь `data-*` аттрибут на `option` и уже забирать значение оттуда, так надежнее

```js
class Select {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node) return;

    this.array = [];
    this.send = this.node.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
    this.select = this.node.querySelector('#select');

    this.onSelectClick = this.onSelectClick.bind(this);
    this.onSendClick = this.onSendClick.bind(this);

    this.select.addEventListener('click', this.onSelectClick, false);
    this.send.addEventListener('click', this.onSendClick, false);
  }

  onSelectClick(e) {
    const option = e.target.closest('option');

    if (!option) return;

    this.pushToArray(option.textContent);
  }

  pushToArray(value) {
    if (!this.isItemChoosen(value)) {
      this.array.push(value);
      console.log(this.array);
    }
  }

  isItemChoosen(value) {
    return ~this.array.indexOf(value);
  }

  onSendClick() {
    // Send data
    console.log(this.array);

    // after send data
    this.array = [];
  }
}

new Select(document.querySelector('#test'));
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <select multiple id="select">
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test3</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

**UPD.** Либо так, выбрать данные через <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

```js
fetch('/path/to/handler', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new FormData(document.querySelector('#test'))
});
```

Comment: отличный код.Спасибо.